# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in PrefixtoPostFix Stack (Java)

Tags: java, stack, postfix-mta, prefix, stringindexoutofbounds

There's two classes in this project. The Main method is the Test2 and the child class is the Stack. The error part here is this part:

Stack s = new Stack(20);

And whenever I run it, it outputs like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at com.stack.Test2.prefixToPostfix(Test2.java:31)
    at com.stack.Test2.main(Test2.java:18)
```

How should I put the "n items" if the Stack generics keeps responding error?

Main Method below:

```
 package com.stack;
        import java.util.Stack;
        //PREFIX TO POSTFIX
        public class Test2 {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String prefix1 = "A + B * C";
                System.out.println(prefixToPostfix(prefix1));
            }

    static String prefixToPostfix(String prefix) {
        Stack<String> s = new Stack(100); 
        String[] tokens = prefix.split(" ");
        for (int i = tokens.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            String token = tokens[i];
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(token.charAt(i))) { 
                String op1 = s.peek(); s.pop();
                String op2 = s.peek(); s.pop();
                String exp = op1 + op2 + token;
                s.push(exp); 
            } 
            else {
                s.push(token + " "); 
            } 
        } 
        return s.peek(); 
    } 
}
```

THIS ONE'S THE STACK OPERATIONS FOR ISEMPTY, ISFULL, PEEK, PUSH, ETC.

```
package com.stack;
public class Stack<T> {  
    int size;
    T A[];
    int top = -1;

    public Stack(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        A = (T[]) new Object[size];
        top = -1;
    }
    public void push(T item) {
        top++;
        A[top] = item;
    }

    public void pop() {
        top--;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
        if(top == - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public T peek() {
        return A[top];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(token.charAt(i)))
```

with this

```
  if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(token.charAt(0)))
```

you are getting this error because length of each variable in your token array is 1 and you are trying to get character at 4th position.